# Prove that there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by...

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Suppose $p>0$. Prove that there is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the associated norm is given by $\|(x,y)\|=(x^p+y^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $p=2$.

I have already shown that there is no inner product if $p\ne2$, but I am a little stuck on proving that one does exist for $p=2$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is not $p=2$ the standard case? $x\cdot y=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$

Comment: If ˆ$p$ is odd, it can't be a norm as it can take negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A norm $\|\cdot\|$ in a real vector space comes from a inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ if and only if the parallelogram law $$\|{\bf x}+{\bf y}\|^2+\|{\bf x}-{\bf y}\|^2 = 2(\|{\bf x}\|^2+\|{\bf y}\|^2)$$holds, in which case the polarization formula holds: $$\langle {\bf x},{\bf y}\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\|{\bf x}+{\bf y}\|^2-\|{\bf x}-{\bf y}\|^2).$$

Comment: It is notable, for those unfamiliar to such things, that these identities are all easily provable by replacing $||v||^2$ by $\langle v,v\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

For $p=2$, try the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : \mathbb{R}^2 \times  \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\left\langle (x,y), (x',y') \right\rangle = xx'+yy'
$$
Then
$$
\|(x,y)\|= \sqrt{ \left\langle (x,y), (x,y) \right\rangle } = \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{1/2}
$$